# Trying to write code to generate 1mb file but it keeps coming up8.4mb

Tags: objective-c, xcode, filesize

I'm not  good yet but my code so far

```
int numberOfBits=8388608;
NSString*outPutFolder=@"/Users/brian/Desktop/Megabytefile.txt";

NSMutableArray*starArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:1];

for (int a=0; a<=numberOfBits; a++) {
    int Randnum = arc4random() % 2;
    [starArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:Randnum]];
}

NSLog(@"Your bit string=%@",[starArray componentsJoinedByString:@""]);

NSString*newfile= [starArray componentsJoinedByString:@""];
[newfile writeToFile:outPutFolder atomically:(YES)];
```

When I click run, the output file is 8.4Mb not 1Mb.

Help please, I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

change

int numberOfBits=8388608;

to

int numberOfBits=1000000;

it should really be called numberOfBytes - each int number requires a byte not a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Your array contains `8388608` numbers each being either `0` or `1`. The string that results from joining these number also has a length of `8388608`. When you use `[NSString writeToFile: atomically:]` without a specific encoding, it seems to fallback to using ASCII which means one byte per character. So `8388608` characters will yield

```
8388608 bytes = (8388608 / 1024 / 1024) mega bytes = 8 mega bytes
```

If you're desired file size is one mega byte, divide `numberOfBits` by `8`.

By the way, `[NSString writeToFile: atomically:]` was deprecated in favor of the more specific variant `[NSString writeToFile: atomically: encoding: error:]`.